# Limit in Postgresql WINDOW partition definition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say you have two tables:

Orders

```
order_id , ....
1, ...
2, ...
```

Each order has a 'state history'. This is stored in a history table:

```
serial, date, order_id , order_state
10,     2012-01-01, 1,  'INIT'
11,     2012-01-02, 2,  'INIT'
12,     2012-02-03, 1,  'COMPLETED'
13,     2012-02-04, 1,  'DISPATCHED'
14,     2012-02-05, 2,  'COMPLETED'
15,     2012-02-06, 2,  'DISPATCHED'
```

Now I want to know at any given point in the past the state of all my orders. So for instance, I want to know the state of orders at 2012-02-05:

```
order_id, order_state, state_date
1 ,      'DISPATCHED' , 2012-02-04
2,       'COMPLETED'  , 2012-02-05
```

(The state_date column is optional).

Is there a way to write one query that does that *more efficiently* than looping through the orders and getting its 'state at given date' in the application code?

I've done that alright with rank() WINDOW function in Postgresql, but I'm not very happy about the fact it has to fetch ALL the history (before the given date) just to pick the one of rank 1. In my view it's not really better than doing it in the app code.

```
SELECT *  FROM ( SELECT o.order_id,
                       h.order_state,
                       h.state_date,
                       rank() ON (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY h.serial DESC)
                              AS hrank
                FROM order o, history h
                WHERE
                     h.order_id = o.order_id AND
                     h.date < given_date
               ) AS rh
WHERE
   rh.hrank = 1;
```

What I would really like is some sort of LIMIT 1 in my Partition definition, but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: "In my view it's not really better than doing it in the app code." Is this view based on **actually** comparing the performance of doing it in the app code against the performance of doing it in the query? Are you interested in improving the performance of your query, or is this intended to be a hypothetical discussion of the limitations of PostgreSQL?

Comment: BTW: don't use `serial` as a column name. It is a reserved word. The same for `date`

Comment: A Colleague has suggested that if I maintain an exit_date  on the history table, then the query becomes trivial: SELECT * FROM history h  JOIN ... WHERE h.date <= given_date AND ( h.exit_date IS NULL OR h.exit_date >= given_date ) .. ;

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah, this is pseudo code, no worries :)

Comment: I am not willing to debug pseudo code.

Comment: No one spoke of a bug :)

Comment: @jeje: Your colleague is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eece0/1)

```
select distinct on (o.order_id) o.order_id, h.order_state, h.date
from
    orders o
    inner join
    history h on h.order_id = o.order_id
where
    h.date <= '2012-02-05'
order by o.order_id, h.date desc
```

`distinct on` will return the first according to the declared order. In this case the most recent date.

Comment: Thanks for the DISTINCT ON tip. I'll use that, but in combination with the exit_date technique, so this distinct only acts when there are multiple state changes at the same point in time (for instance, when multiple state changes happen in the same transaction, which is rare).

Answer (score 1):

This might be faster:

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
       h.order_state,
       h.state_date,
FROM "order" o 
  JOIN history h ON h.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE h.order_date = (select max(h2.order_date)
                      from history h2
                      where h2.order_id = h.order_id 
                      and h2.order_date <= date '2012-02-05');
```

(Note that the join between order and history is not really necessary here, but I assume your example query was just a subset of what you really want)

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS() tot the rescue:

```
SELECT o.order_id
  -- h.zserial -- you might want to see this as well
  , h.order_state
  , h.state_date
FROM zorder o
JOIN history h ON h.order_id = o.order_id
    -- You probably don't need this date comparison,
    -- ,since it is already in the subquery
WHERE h.zdate < given_date
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM history nx
    WHERE nx.order_id = o.order_id
    AND nx.zdate < given_date
    AND nx.zserial > h.zserial
    );
```

Note: I changed the column names to names that don't conflict with keywords.

Comment: Didn't you forget to change `FROM order` to something else? Or `order` in that context does not matter?